# Searching a model's records base on an attribute of another model which has related to this one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two model classes `class A` and `class B`. The second class is related to the first using a foreign key. I want to be able to search `class A` objects by an attribute of `class B` (inside django admin):

```py
class A(models.Model):
    a1 = models.CharField()
    a2 = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    b1 = models.CharField()

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['a1', 'b1']

admin.site.register(A, AAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `related_name` to your Foreign Key and use it for the lookup you need:

```
class A(models.Model):
    a1 = models.CharField()
    a2 = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='something')
    b1 = models.CharField()

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['a1', 'something__b1']

admin.site.register(A, AAdmin)
```

Comment: the default related name is `b_set`. But for lookups it's just the related model's name lowercased, i.e. `b`. So without adding `related_name`, it also works: `search_fields = ['b__b1']`